# Include search paths from included header varies for different compilers

Tags: c++, gcc, cl

I have following folder structure:

```
project
├── header1.h
├── folder
│   └── header2.h
└── main.cpp
```

With following sources:

```
//main.cpp
#include "header1.h"
#include "folder/header2.h"
int main() {}

//header1.h
#pragma once
void function1() {}

//folder/header2.h
#pragma once
#include "header1.h"
void function2() {}
```

So 'header2.h' is including 'header1.h' which is not in the same folder.

Compiling this code with `cl main.cpp` is successful:

> ```
> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> main.cpp Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.24215.1
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> /out:main.exe main.obj
> ```

But for `gcc main.cpp` I get error:

> ```
> In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
> folder/header2.h:2:21: fatal error: header1.h: No such file or directory
>  #include "header1.h"
>                      ^
> compilation terminated.
> ```

Which totally makes sense. Seems like Microsoft is using their own rules to resolve includes. 
Is there a way to disable this behavior for `cl` (and Visual Studio)?
Is there a way to enable cl-like behavior for `gcc`?

---

UPD.

I have checked with Clang 4.0.0 `clang++ main.cpp` on Windows:

> ```
> In file included from main.cpp:2:
> ./folder/header2.h:2:10: warning: #include resolved using non-portable Microsoft search rules as: ./header1.h
> ```
>
> [-Wmicrosoft-include]
>       #include "header1.h"
>                ^
>       1 warning generated.

And it even has a specific rule `-Wmicrosoft-include` for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4.aspx) explains how both forms (`""` and `<>`) of `include` directive is processed by the VC++.

I guess that point **(3)** of the `""` form causes this very broad search across possible include directories in the project:

> **Quoted form**
>
> **(3)** In the directories of the currently opened include files, in the
>   reverse order in which they were opened. The search begins in the
>   directory of the parent include file and continues upward through the
>   directories of any grandparent include files.

That is why, when `header2.h` is processed from within `main.cpp`, which also includes `header1.h`, it gives you no error.

GCC search rules are quite different:

> 1. For the quote form of the include directive, the directory of the current file is searched first.
> 2. For the quote form of the include directive, the directories specified by -iquote options are searched in left-to-right order, as
>      they appear on the command line.
> 3. Directories specified with -I options are scanned in left-to-right order.
> 4. Directories specified with -isystem options are scanned in left-to-right order.
> 5. Standard system directories are scanned.
> 6. Directories specified with -idirafter options are scanned in left-to-right order.

It does not automatically search the directories of include files that were opened so far (included before), which is the cause of your error. I don't think there is a way to bypass this limitation and force either of the compilers to use search logic used by another one.